# Blogger showing wrong thumbnail image on facebook

Tags: facebook, blogger

Hello I changed my blog template recently and I'm having trouble showing the right images for thumbnail during my share on facebook.

Here is my blog please help thank you. http://gakuenftw.blogspot.com/

Comment: Try passing your URL through the Facebook debugger and fix any errors you may have. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1):

Works for me ...

Also debug the Open Graph meta data, seems fine...

[image]

Comment: How? I use the debug tool and i got this error must be fix "Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable."

Answer (score 0):

You need to optimize your meta tags, make sure nothing repetitive and also check meta description and the thumbnail tag that's attached with the original blogger templates.

```
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
```